# Jmeter csv variable that refers to another csv

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

In Jmeter I've defined two CSV Data Set Config.
First one contains some columns:

```
Name, Surname, Adress, ....
```

In the second one I would like configure a column that takes the value from the first CSV Data Set Config:

```
SecondName = ${Name}, Age, ...
```

For the SecondName I've tryied these values, but no valid result:

```
${Name}
${__evalVar(Name)})
${__eval(${Name})}
${__V(${Name})}
${__groovy(vars.get("Name"))}
```

Please could you help me to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

Take a look at [JMeter Test Elements Execution Order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)

```
0. Configuration elements
1. Pre-Processors
2. Timers
3. Sampler
4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
```

- CSV Data Set Config is a configuration element therefore it's initialized before anything else
- The variable is being read when a thread (virtual user) executes a Sampler
- So your 2nd CSV Data Set Config is getting the variable value at step 3 and being initialized at step 0 when the variable doesn't exist/has the value yet

The solution would be migrating to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead), see [How to Pick Different CSV Files at JMeter Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-pick-different-csv-files-at-jmeter-runtime) article for more details.